# Code is not working in content place holder

Tags: javascript, master-pages, contentplaceholder

Hi I am making blank the textboxes  through javascript code on client side.

If I use this code without masterpage it works perfectly, but I I use master page it doesn't work. why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function clrCtrl() {
      var control = "<%=txtpassword.ClientID %>";
      var control2 = "<%=txtConfirmpassword.ClientID %>";
      document.getElementById(control).value = "";
      document.getElementById(control2).value = "";

  }
</script>
```

below is my radiobutton and dropdownlist

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" CssClass="nbdcontent"     AutoPostBack="True"
                            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium"     onchange="clrCtrl()" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0">CPMU</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">SPMU</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2">SFTI</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>


<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStates" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                            CssClass="mytextbox" DataTextField="State" DataValueField="State_Id" Enabled="False"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStates_SelectedIndexChanged1" 
                            onchange="clrCtrl()">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Can you debug the java script and see whether it is getting executed or not ?

Comment: no it is not coming under breakpint. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I create this js function for finding all elements in page. If element (control) id doesn't have prefix `ct100_ContentPlaceholder1_` (or something like this), if not content of `master` or `conten` page, function `getElement` will immediately return control/element, will avoid looping trough complete page, otherwise it will search.

```
function getElement(id) {
    if (document.getElementById(id) == null) {
        var pp = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
        for (var i = 0; i < pp.length; i++) {
            if (pp[i].id != null) {
                var ele = pp[i].id;
                if (ele.indexOf('_') > -1) {
                    //spliter is _
                    var tt = ele.split('_');
                    if (tt[tt.length - 1] == id) { return pp[i]; }
                }
                if (ele.indexOf('$') > -1) {
                    //spliter is $ 
                    var tt = ele.split('$');
                    if (tt[tt.length - 1] == id) { return pp[i]; }
                }
            }
        }
        // element not found, return nothing
        return null;
    } else {
        // element is not in contentplaceholder
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }
}
```

It will loop trough all elements in page.
Then You can use in Your code :

```
function clrCtrl() {
      getElement('txtpassword').value='';
      getElement('txtConfirmpassword').value='';
}
```

But, it's very important one thing : **don't use _ char in Your control(s) id**. That is a condition, otherwise `function` will return `null`.
eg. if Your `textbox` `id` is `txt_password`, `function` will return `null`, will not find Your control.

p.s. sorry for weak English.